# How to filter data on one table based on reference data on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have two tables `account_agent` and `bulk_index`. The data on each table is as follows

`account_agent`

```
name         code         account         remark         scheme
avi          10           151362          first          as
babi         11           123478          new            as
avi          10           151721          new            as
avi          10           151765          new            as
sam          sas/01       925458          tin            sas
```

`bulk_index`

```
agentcode         account          customer_name
10                151362           Alok
22                265721           Rohan
10                151721           Akash
```

using these tables I want result on `account_agent` table as follows

`account_agent`

```
name         code         account         remark
avi          10           151362          first
avi          10           151721          new
```

I have tried the query

```
select * from account_agent where code = '10' and account = (select account from bulk_index where code = '10')
```

Comment: Are you asking how to join tables and do a `WHERE` clause?  What have you tried?

Comment: not clear what you are asking, what are the rules for the selection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This query worked for me

```
SELECT A.name, A.code, A.Account, A.remark, A.scheme
FROM account_agent A
INNER JOIN bulk_index B ON A.account = B.account 
WHERE A.scheme = 'as' AND A.code = '10'
```

Comment: If you are looking for `A.Scheme` to be equal to 'as'. Then I don't really see a reason why using `like` would be necessary. If you are interested in only certain characters in the scheme column values then you would need to use wildcard (%) as needed in your like statement. Please see my updated answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `account` column is unique, you could just do a simple join and a where clause to get this:

```
SELECT A.name, A.code, A.Account, A.remark
FROM account_agent A
INNER JOIN bulk_index B ON A.account = B.account 
WHERE a.scheme like '%as%' and a.code = '10' 
--remove the preceeding or succeeding % in like as needed
```

If you are only interested in values where `scheme` column is equal to 'as' and `code` is equal to 10, then you could just do this:

```
SELECT A.name, A.code, A.Account, A.remark
FROM account_agent A
INNER JOIN bulk_index B ON A.account = B.account 
WHERE a.scheme = 'as' and a.code = '10'
```

Here is a link to W3Schools page which explains the use of like operator in sql.

[SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,code,account,remark
from account_agent
where exists(select bulk_index.agentcode from bulk_index where bulk_index.agentcode = account_agent.code)
```

this code will show all the data that account_agent table **code** exists in bulk_index table **agentcode**

Answer (score 0):

This will only return data that is related in the bulk_index table:

```
SELECT A.name, A.code, A.Account, A.remark
FROM account_agent A
INNER JOIN bulk_index B
   ON A.account = B.account AND A.code = B.agentcode
```

Comment: what should be done if the `account_agent.code` has values other than `integer` datatype?

Comment: If the relationship of account is enough, then you could just take out the code join.  Otherwise, it would just ignore any criteria that doesn't match.